# How old does my code work correctly if I don't update it to the new versions of numpy and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, version

I have been developing a project and the intention is to leave it as free, but I am concerned that over the years (my question is how many) my code will stop working because the versions of Numpy, pandas, and Matplotlib change

I just want to know how long my code will last if I don't update it

Comment: The safest way is to create a list of your dependencies with their versions... something like `pip freeze > requirements`

Comment: Hard to save answer without knowing the exact code. If you want your code  to work reliably, you should package it with defined versions of the libraries.

Comment: For a start, make sure you aren't seeing, or hiding, any deprecation warnings.  I don't know about the other packages, but `numpy` shouldn't have many age issues.  There are some legacy uses that are being phased out, but you should be getting warnings if you try to use those.  Code using the standard numeric dtypes should be most stable.  I'd avoid `object` dtype arrays.  And `ndarray` subclasses (like `np.matrix`).

Comment: A possibly relevant document: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/depending_on_numpy.html and https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0023-backwards-compatibility.html#nep23